# Loading css in Rails

Tags: css, ruby-on-rails-4, asset-pipeline

I'm having trouble understanding the asset pipeline and how does the css load order works.. I try to make edits to my css but "application.css" takes precedence over them so they don't work.

Could someone please enlighten me?

Answer (score 0):

Using asset pipeline - all the stylesheets are loaded in the order which is mentioned in application.css.

Ex: *= require jquery_ui
    *= require_tree .

Here first the styles in the jquery_ui loads and then other stylesheets get loaded.

If you can paste the order here an tell me which stylesheet you want to be loaded i can help you.

Comment: ` 
 *= require_tree .
 *= require_self

@import "bootstrap"
@import "bootstrap-sprockets"`

That is currently how my `application.css.sass` looks like. This file is `.sass` but the other 2 are `.scss`  Is that a problem ?